# Removing text field created with a SpringLayout

Tags: java, springlayout

I'm using the code from the example on the official page of Oracle. The one for sorting and filtering table data. In the original variant it has two fields - one for entering a filtering criteria and second for showing which row from the grid is selected. I don't need the second one, want to leave just the filter field, but it seems that I miss something. Below is my code with comments on the code I thought was unnecessary :

```
public TableFilterDemo() {
        super();
        setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        //Create a table with a sorter.
        MyTableModel model = new MyTableModel("customers.dat");
        sorter = new TableRowSorter<MyTableModel>(model);
        table = new JTable(model);
        table.setRowSorter(sorter);
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 70));
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

        //For the purposes of this example, better to have a single
        //selection.
      //  table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);

        //When selection changes, provide user with row numbers for
        //both view and model.
     /*   table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(
                new ListSelectionListener() {
                    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent event) {
                        int viewRow = table.getSelectedRow();
                        if (viewRow < 0) {
                            //Selection got filtered away.
                            statusText.setText("");
                        } else {
                            int modelRow = 
                                table.convertRowIndexToModel(viewRow);
                            statusText.setText(
                                String.format("Selected Row in view: %d. " +
                                    "Selected Row in model: %d.", 
                                    viewRow, modelRow));
                        }
                    }
                }
        );
*/

        //Create the scroll pane and add the table to it.
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

        //Add the scroll pane to this panel.
        add(scrollPane);

        //Create a separate form for filterText and statusText
        JPanel form = new JPanel(new SpringLayout());
        JLabel l1 = new JLabel("Student Number:", SwingConstants.TRAILING);
        form.add(l1);
        filterText = new JTextField();
        //Whenever filterText changes, invoke newFilter.
        filterText.getDocument().addDocumentListener(
                new DocumentListener() {
                    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                        newFilter();
                    }
                    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                        newFilter();
                    }
                    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                        newFilter();
                    }
                });
        l1.setLabelFor(filterText);
        form.add(filterText);
       /* JLabel l2 = new JLabel("Status:", SwingConstants.TRAILING);
        form.add(l2);
        statusText = new JTextField();
        l2.setLabelFor(statusText);
        form.add(statusText); */ 
        SpringUtilities.makeCompactGrid(form, 2, 2, 6, 6, 6, 6);
        add(form);
    }
```

I get a lot of mistakes when I try ti compile but the first is:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: No such child: 2

Answer (score 0):

The commented block is not needed but along with it the 2nd parameter passed in `SpringUtilities.makeCompactGrid(form, 1, 2, 6, 6, 6, 6);` should be changed from `2` like it is in my original question to `1` like it's here.